# SOAP API Request Gives Internal Server Error, but same request works in SoapUI

Tags: api, soap, gack

I'm making the following request from Salesforce to an external API (a 3rd party I can't seem to get the logs from):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:deal="http://www.adt.com/DealerAPI/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <wsse:Security>
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>10753675</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>1234</wsse:Password>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <deal:napeCheckRequest>
         <dealerNumber>10753675</dealerNumber>
         <custLastName>Davis</custLastName>
         <custFirstName>Joshua</custFirstName>
         <businessName />
         <streetAddress>495 University Ave</streetAddress>
         <city>Orem</city>
         <state>UT</state>
         <zip>84058</zip>
         <phone>8018001234</phone>
      </deal:napeCheckRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I keep getting this in the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<NS1:Envelope xmlns:NS1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <NS1:Body>
      <NS1:Fault>
         <faultcode>NS1:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ADT DealerAPI - {http://www.adt.com/DealerAPI/}napeCheck Service Error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <NS2:getDealerAPIFault xmlns:NS2="http://www.adt.com/DealerAPI/">
               <errorCode>9999</errorCode>
               <errorMessage>Internal server error</errorMessage>
            </NS2:getDealerAPIFault>
         </detail>
      </NS1:Fault>
   </NS1:Body>
</NS1:Envelope>
```

I get that even though I can copy that same request into SoapUI and get a non-error response. I'm not a developer, but it has to be related to Salesforce since everything works fine in SoapUI. Please help!

Comment: You could check what headers are being sent by SoapUI and duplicate those. But you can't do anything about e.g. the (Salesforce) domain that the request is sent from so getting the service vendor to explain what 9999 means seems like the way to go (though it sounds like you've already tried to do that).

Comment: @eddie-prignano In theory SOAP UI will just be POSTing the same request to the web service URL. Is it possible that the web service provider has an IP restriction in place for incoming requests. What happens if you make the same request using SOAP UI from a different IP address. You could try making the raw HTTP request from Apex.